# Shortcut for mirroring touch bar

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, touch-bar

I would like to see an emulated touchbar on my iMac.

I randomly pressed the shotcut for it, but I don't know, which it was and I couldn't find it one the internet either. Btw., I don't use an Apple keyboard, so i.e. the fn key is missing.

[image: Touch Bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show the Touch Bar on your screen using Xcode by choosing Window → Show Touch Bar or shift-cmd-8.